# IPv6 what do I really need to connect?

Tags: ipv6

I this bound to be a duplicate, but I can't find the answer.

Lets say I have a TCP service running. With IPv4 I have to provide the clients with the server's IP and the port my service is listening on.

What information I have to provide to the clients so that they can connect with IPv6?

- IP and Port?
- IP, Port and  Scope ID?
- IP, Port, Scope ID and Flow Info?

Answer (score 1):

Just like with IPv4, ip and (sometime port) should be enough, please note that in some case you need to "format" the Ip so it's understood by the application, for example in a browser you have to encapsulate the IPv6 in [] so for example http://[2604:a880:800:10::8fc:8001]/ other protocol such as ssh don't need this. If you happen to setup a AAAA record with the IPv6 in your DNS then you can just access the server via it's name, resolution will point to the IPv6.

Comment: Could you elaborate why that is the case? I would have expected ScopeID to be required to cover all corner cases with link-local addresses.

Comment: A computer can have multiple link-local addresses, each with a different scope. The scope ID indicates which scope the address is for. For example, imagine the scenario of a computer with two NICs, each with a link-local address on different networks. If you try to send something to another address beginning with fe80, how will the computer know which NIC to send out on? The scope ID appears to be the solution for this. (I found this here http://superuser.com/questions/99746/why-is-there-a-percent-sign-in-the-ipv6-address)

Comment: So... do I need to provide the clients with the scopeid? I think I've read somewhere that it is specific to the local host, basically an alias for the interface name. That would imply that the client needs to figure out the scopeid by themselves.